# How to update imutils in anaconda?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, imutils

I tired with a command prompt but I'm getting **this error**:

```
Cannot uninstall 'imutils'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it.
```

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Which OS? Ubuntu? Windows?

Comment: it is windows 10 bro